# Apply a class on hover to a textbox and td elements using CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to apply a class `valError` to a td element and two input text boxes.

Sample code is at this URL: [demo for this question](http://js.do/sun21170/77268). I have used the following code, but it doesn't do anything when hovering over the td or any of the input text boxes. I have set the class to `valError` for the td and the input text boxes but still it doesn't help.

**Question** : How can I make sure that the class `valError` is applied when hovering over the `td` element or any of the text boxes? I wanted to do this using pure CSS without JavaScript or jQuery.

**Html Code**

```
<style>
   .valError input[type='text']:hover {
   border: 2px solid red !important;
   background-color: lightyellow !important;
   color: red !important;
   }
   .valError td:hover {
   border: 2px solid red !important;
   background-color: lightyellow !important;
   color: red !important;
   }
</style>
<table>
   <tr>
      <td class='valError'>
         <!--some content here-->
         Hello I am a td element
      </td>
      <td>
         <table>
            <tr>
               <td>
                  First Name 
               </td>
               <td>
                  <input type='text' id='firstname' class='valError'>  
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>
                  Last Name 
               </td>
               <td>
                  <input type='text' id='lastname' class='valError'>
               </td>
            </tr>
         </table>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the space between class and tag.

```
<style>
    input[type='text'].valError:hover {
       border: 2px solid red !important;
       background-color: lightyellow !important;
       color: red !important;
   }
   td.valError:hover {
       border: 2px solid red !important;
       background-color: lightyellow !important;
       color: red !important;
   }
</style>
```

Comment: Yes, great. You are a CSS genius. Thanks.

Comment: So class name should always follow the element type selector and hover should be the last part?

Comment: It's the space between element and typeselector. Your original code is looking for child elements of the type `input` or `td`, inside an element with the class `.valError`. No space means "elements with type ... **and** the class"

Comment: The class name should always follow the type selector, to mark the end of the class name: `.valErrorinput` != `input.valError`

Comment: Excellent explanation

Comment: Sorry I thought I marked this as answer, but just noticed that it hadn't been marked.